# PyPy JIT calling optimization

Tags: jit, pypy

Consider a following code snippet:

```
class Duck:
    def duck(self):
        pass

ducks = [Duck() for i in range(10)]
for duck in ducks:
   duck.duck() #<-----
```

Will the duck.duck() call be dynamically dispatched (i.e. every time the method lookup will be done), or the JIT will be able to deduct that we are iterating over a stable list of ducks and substitute calls with mem+offset?

If yes, then how maybe I can see it myself (i.e. how to check IR code, if there is any or the generated assembly); if no, then why?

Comment: It's a tracing JIT, so the loop will turn into "check that the type of 'duck' is 'Duck'; then do nothing more (the method is inlined)".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People in the PyPy team are working on a reasonable way to do that for external people.  In the meantime, here are the instructions for the current way to view the IR (and optionally machine code) produced by the JIT compiler.

These instructions were tested on Linux.  They should also work on OS/X.  For Windows, you need to adapt the syntax of most commands, as usual.

- check out a copy of the main PyPy repository (takes a long time!): e.g. for the 5.x releases, `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy -r release-5.x -u release-5.x pypysrc`
- install https://bitbucket.org/pypy/jitviewer for PyPy (usually we do that by checking it out with `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/pypy/jitviewer`, and then `virtualenv -p pypy pypy-venv; . pypy-venv/bin/activate; cd /path/to/jitviewer; pypy setup.py install`)
- run your example program like this: `PYPYLOG=jit:log pypy mytest.py`; this produces a file called `log`
- view the log by starting `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/pypysrc jitviewer.py --log log` and then viewing the url at `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`.

Comment: Nowadays, replace all the links from ``https://bitbucket.org/pypy/...`` to ``https://foss.heptapod.net/pypy/...``.